# How to add one read-only field to an object instance

Tags: apex

I often have to write code like the following (especially in test classes) and am wondering if it is necessary:

```
RecordType rc = [select Id from RecordType where SobjectType = 'Account' AND IsPersonType = True limit 1];
Account joe = new Account( FirstName = 'Joe', LastName = 'Blogs', RecordTypeId = rc.Id);

joe.fieldOne__c = 'this';
joe.fieldTwo__c = 'that';
...
joe.fieldThirteen__c = 'phew! test fixture done';
insert joe;

// now I want to populate the Id for joe's contact record, but I can't do this:
joe.PersonContactId = [Select PersonContactId from Account where Id = :joe.Id limit 1].PersonContactId; // crash, field is readonly

// I am forced to use this hard to maintain way
joe = [select 
    Id, Name, PersonContactId,
    fieldOne__c, fieldTwo__c,
    rememberToAddThisOne__c,
    dontForgetThisOne__c,
    youNeedThisLaterOn__c,
    ....
    from Account
    where Id = :joe.Id limit1];
];
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
joe.loadAllFields();
```

or second best:

```
joe.keepWhatYouHaveAndLoad('PersonContactId');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a utility class and use the getDescribe methods to dynamically build your object. It might be a little overkill but depending on what you are trying to ultimately do could save you quite a bit of time.

Example:
http://www.oyecode.com/2012/08/utility-class-how-to-get-all-fields-for.html

Comment: Thanks, TC. It might come in handy in other situations, but it is rather heavy to use in this type of case.